# Swift - Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm getting the error after `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` runs several times.
Here's thing: I've create a `teacherArray` that contains the data used for the cell, and it surely contains what I need.
I used the storyboard to customize the cell and the tableview. And I've checked that the identifier for cell is set, and I also customized the class for the tableview and the cell in the identity inspector.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return teacherArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as SearchCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = teacherArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.schoolLabel.text = teacherArray[indexPath.row].school
    cell.experienceLabel.text = teacherArray[indexPath.row].experience
    cell.courseLabel.text = teacherArray[indexPath.row].course

    println(indexPath.row)
    println(cell)

    return cell
}
```

I've tracked the method, and it's after this console output:

```
6
PAL.SearchCell: 0x7bf32310; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 450; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf322e0>
```

...that I get this error message:

```
 2015-04-26 22:27:54.880 PAL[65213:6357947]*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:7344
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong. Any idea?

Comment: You are probably getting a `nil` from the `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method. Double check the cell identifiers match in the storyboard and code. Also access the tableview using the method param in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` - at the moment you're using a property, (`self.tableView` not `tableView`). which might be your problem if you aren't using a plain `UITableViewController` and you haven't hooked up the outlet.

Comment: @RichTolley Thanks for your help.Because my company's server is done.I can't do the exact test for now. But when I use the array that contains 0 to 19 to replace the teacherArray to fill the cell.I won't get the error.It in some aspects may means that what I've done in the storyboard maybe is right.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
add UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate:
class HDMainHotBoleCtr: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {    
}
```

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tbv.register(UINib(nibName: "HDHotResumeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HDHotResumeCell")
    }